# is_user_logged_in() isn't working

Tags: functions, login

I'm making a login form for my site, and I've this section:

```
<?php
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    echo 'Hello, ', $user_login, '. <a href="', wp_logout_url(), '" title="Logout">Logout</a>';
} else {
    wp_login_form();
}
```

And after loggin in, it returns to the page with no indication of logging in.
I suspect `is_user_logged_in()` isn't working, but I don't know how to debug this problem.

EDIT:
Whenever I do this:

```
global $current_user;
var_dump($current_user);
```

I always get:

```
ect(WP_User)#3 (7) { ["data"]=> NULL ["ID"]=> int(0) ["caps"]=> array(0) { } ["cap_key"]=> NULL ["roles"]=> array(0) { } ["allcaps"]=> array(0) { } ["filter"]=> NULL }
```

No matter if i've 'logged' in with the above form.

Comment: Disable all caching plugins and your browser cache. Does it still happen?

Comment: Yeah, I tried deleting the cache. 

I should mention that I'm trying to implement wordpress into an existing website.  

So I don't really want to use any plugins or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the function, it's the fact that you aren't actually being logged in!

You say you're making your own login form? Does this post to the standard `wp-login.php`, or do you handle the request yourself?

Does the path/domain of the form differ from WordPress? If you [inspect your cookies](http://getfirebug.com/), are any being set?

Comment: I'm using `wp_login_form()` 

And as for path/domain, I'm not really sure. 

I'm using chrome, and according to the debugging profile thing, it suggests: 


Domain:localhost
Path:/
Date:Fri, 10 Aug 2012 11:14:30 GMT
Size:70

Comment: And for the form, it's stored in: 

`http://localhost/newgameplus/TEST/scripts/php/testWP.php`

And the wordpress install is: 

`http://localhost/newgameplus/wordpress/`

Comment: I think that's the issue - WordPress will set a cookie with the path `/newgameplus/wordpress/`, which won't be read under `/newgameplus/TEST/scripts/php/testWP.php`. Try `define( 'COOKIEPATH', '/' );` in your `wp-config.php`

Comment: By the way, I'd highly recommend using virtual hosts to develop on: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32331/wordpress-local-development-environment

Answer (score 0):

I know it is pretty late, but I am adding my answer to help others. If you use `wp_signon()` function to login, and verify with `is_user_logged_in()` thereafter, you need to set the current user with `wp_set_current_user()` first because `wp_signon()` does not handle setting the current user as described in the WP codex:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/

This is one of the reasons why the function `is_user_logged_in()` says false when you thought you have logged in a user already.